# Android TCP Smartphone to PC with USB no wifi

Tags: android

Hi I have managed some code but its not working

I want to control send message from PC To Android over my application via USB not by **WIFI**

i tried this code

But it's giving me error that

```
07-13 20:08:28.530: W/System.err(8990): java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:383 - Connection refused
```

I have done port forward by ***adb***

For Desktop

```
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class comunicate {

 public static void main(String[] args){
  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  Socket socket = null;
  DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

  try {
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(383);
   System.out.println("Listening :8888");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  while(true){
   try {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
    System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello!");
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally{
    if( socket!= null){
     try {
      socket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if( dataInputStream!= null){
     try {
      dataInputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if( dataOutputStream!= null){
     try {
      dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

For Mobile

```
package demo.app.org;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DemoAppActivity extends Activity {

EditText textOut;
TextView textIn;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
     Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
     textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
     buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
 }

 Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener
 = new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Socket socket = null;
 DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
 DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

 try {
  socket = new Socket("localhost", 383);
  dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
  textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally{
  if (socket != null){
   try {
    socket.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  if (dataOutputStream != null){
   try {
    dataOutputStream.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  if (dataInputStream != null){
   try {
    dataInputStream.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
}};
}
```

Comment: Ports below 1024 are *reserved*.

Comment: have you checked `adb help` for any clues?

Comment: yes but adb -h and help but no solution at the moment

Btw is it possible to communicate with USB or you can give me example without wifi or net

Comment: `adb usb                      - restarts the adbd daemon listening on USB`, or ... ` adb forward <local> <remote> - forward socket connections
                                 forward specs are one of: 
                                   tcp:<port>
                                   localabstract:<unix domain socket name>
                                   localreserved:<unix domain socket name>
                                   localfilesystem:<unix domain socket name>`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this code for tcp communication over wifi? I think you can not communicate with android over USB except for logcat.

Comment: yes it is i am trying to get it work with USB i think without net connection WIFI,or net we can't communicate but i read on some forums that it's possible by ADB port forward